# I can't get my outgoing-only mail server working on 17.04

Tags: networking, server, email, postfix, mail

I followed this tutorial:

I am using a container purchased on vultr.com: [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-14-04)

For the system mail name in step one, I used the domain name I have pointing to the ip, without any subdomians i.e. `mydoimain.com`

Got to step 3, and nothing is appearing in the mailbox I specify in the command.

```
echo "This is the body of the email" | mail -s "This is the subject line" exampleRecipient@example.com
```

What do I do now?

In `/var/log/mail.log` I see:

```
Apr 20 08:04:14 guest postfix/smtp[7023]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2404:6800:4008:c03::1b]:25: Network is unreachabl
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the message in `/var/log/mail.log` your Postfix tries to forward your test mail to one of Google's mail servers via IPv6. The message `Network is unreachable` means there is no IPv6 connectivity between the two. Since IPv6 mail delivery to Googlemail works generally fine the problem will be with your container.

Possible solutions:

a) Fix your IPv6 connectivity. vultr.com should be able to help you with this.

b) Limit Postfix to IPv4. This can be done by setting

```
inet_protocols = ipv4
```

in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`.

**Note:** There's more to running an outgoing mailserver than just setting up Postfix to deliver mail to servers on the Internet. You have to make sure you have IP addresses from a range that's allowed to send outbound mail, set up proper forward and reverse DNS for the server and preferably an SPF record for the domain you're sending from, create and monitor an abuse address, and monitor your server's reputation. Otherwise the next error message will be some variant of "550 5.7.1 Sender blocked".

Comment: Interesting, I am getting:

* added output to the main post